# Unable find day (Date) wise data in Google Analytics Data php API V4

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I am using google analytics data api using google service Account. I am getting all data but when i try to search date wise data than i am getting on sedding data.I need all data like "Session", "New Sessions", "PageViews" etc. I am using following code

```
   // Create the Metrics object.
   $date = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
   $date->setName("ga:date");

   $pageviews = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
   $pageviews->setExpression("ga:pageviews");
   $pageviews->setAlias("pageviews");


   $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
   $request->setDimensions(array($date));
```

Thank you!

Comment: "getting on sedding data" does not seem to be standard english, can you clarify ?

Comment: I am not getting data